# format time span to show hours, minutes, seconds

Tags: r, time, format

I've been trying to find a simple way of formatting the output from `difftime` into HH:MM:SS.ms. So far I haven't come across anything which I was surprised by.

I did write the function below which almost does it. The limitation is the presentation of the numbers as significant single digits. eg 2hr, 3mins, 4.5secs becomes "2:3:4.5" instead of "02:03:04.5"

Does anyone have a better suggestion?

```
format.timediff <- function(start_time) {
    diff = as.numeric(difftime(Sys.time(), start_time, units="mins"))
    hr <- diff%/%60
    min <- floor(diff - hr * 60)
    sec <- round(diff%%1 * 60,digits=2)

    return(paste(hr,min,sec,sep=':'))
}
```

Comment: @GSee, sprintf is great. I'll definitely use it in the future. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

In addition to @GSee's comment, you could use a function like this:

```
f <- function(start_time) {
  start_time <- as.POSIXct(start_time)
  dt <- difftime(Sys.time(), start_time, units="secs")
  # Since you only want the H:M:S, we can ignore the date...
  # but you have to be careful about time-zone issues
  format(.POSIXct(dt,tz="GMT"), "%H:%M:%S")
}
f(Sys.Date())
```

Comment: thank you very much, that is a lot nicer. I'm a bit confused by the '.' in front of 'POSIXct' so I'll have to do some more reading, but it works brilliantly. I'm fairly new to R and really appreciate your help.

Comment: @getting-there: it's just a simple function that constructs a `POSIXct` object from a numeric vector.

Answer (score 0):

```
Merge_Charge_Point$Duration<- difftime(Merge_Charge_Point$EndConnectionDateTime, Merge_Charge_Point$StartConnectionDateTime, units="secs")
```

This is the code. But this code transforms the data in to seconds but the outcome should be a time string.